# p:dataTable style change?

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces `dataTable` component, like so:

```
<p:dataTable 
 value="#{bean.objects}" var="item"
 paginator="true" 
 rows="10"
 paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} 
                    {PreviousPageLink} 
                    {PageLinks} 
                    {NextPageLink} 
                    {LastPageLink} 
                    {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30,50,100"
 styleClass="shorterDropdown"> 
 <p:column>... 
 </>
</>
```

`paginatorTemplate` adds `RowsPerPageDropdown`. My goal was to change this dropdown width via `shorterDropdown` class in the css file, but it doesn't work. Here is the CSS code:

```
select.shorterDropdown 
{ 
    width:45px;
}
```

How would I change this dropdown's width via CSS?

Comment: In primefaces every element has some class assigned to it. First give an `id` to datatable and and then try `$('#datatableid.ui-paginator-rpp-options').css('width','500px')` in script or `#datatableid.ui-paginator-rpp-options { width:50px }` in your css style class. If you see browser console for `HMTL` of this datatable , you will find these style classes

Comment: Thanks. I added `#datatableid.ui-paginator-rpp-options { width:50px }` to my css file, but - doesn't work. Firebug reveals that this style has not been applied to `ui-paginator-rpp-options`, it is not even strikethrough, I don't see it in anywhere in the final html file. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe I need to add form id `formId:datatableid.ui-paginator-rpp-options`?

Comment: @Danijel..Didn't you find `ui-paginator-rpp-options` class in your firebug? When you highlight that `RowsPerPageDropdown` in the browser, you should see some `StyleClasses` applied to that `<select/>` element. From there you can apply your `custom` style by `overriding` that class.

Comment: Yes, it is there, but the code you supplied didn't work, the style is not applied. I resolved this by adding to CSS file the following: `.ui-paginator-rpp-options { width:50px }`. Does that make sense for you? This adds it to every dropdown in every paginator, but that's what I need for now.

Comment: @Danijel... Did you just exactly use my code as I posted in my comment? What I meant was to give a `ID` to datatable and try with that particular ID and the CSS class I shown in the comment.So, that that style only applies to the particular dropdown inside your datatbale

Comment: Hi, yes I used your code, but I replaced the `datatableid` with my real data table ID.

Answer (score -1):

For override the default  style  of  Primefaces,   edit your CSS  modification   (  use developper tols, to find the css selectors (name of class ....))   then add   "importante !" to  CSS rules like this   style="background: red !important;"

---

For more informations about css priority : (call order: the last called is the one aplied) when at the same level:
     important! > #id > .class > html tag

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do not use !important. If you get the right CSS class, you don't need it!

Comment: @alexander :  as  you  now  it  can work without !important, but we want  to work evry time; 
the key if my answer  is based  on   the priority  of css selectors :
!important  > #id > .class > htmlTags   
is PF we  use absolutely  classes   we  can not  use #id !!!   when to increase th .class  priority    we add !important   that all !!